# Understanding and Controlling Visual Studio 2010 ProjectAssemblies folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

1) What controls what dlls are copied to C:\users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectAssemblies?
2) Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from storing dlls in this folder?

Comment: `AppData` is where applications are allowed to store their own data, instead of eg writing into the protected `Program Files` folder. There's nothing wrong with an application writing into its own folder in there, in fact, that's what any well-behaved application should do. Why do you care what gets written in there? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757373/vs2010-designer-exception-cannot-convert-type-x-to-type-x-duplicate-dlls

Comment: Which answers *this* question. That's where the assemblies used by Visual Studio's designers are stored. Without them there, you'll get the error you posted in the other question. What you ask here is actually going to make things much worse

Answer (score 1):

Richard,

I'm not sure I know what you mean by "caching dlls".  The compiler will pull the dll that the project references in the References folder of the Solution Explorer into the bin folder.  If you have a DLL and you wish to create a newer version of the DLL in a separate location you will have to delete the reference and then add a new reference to the newer version.     I frequently copy the versions of the DLLs that I want to use into the Solution folder then I make a reference to these copies in my project (you have to use Browse).  This accomplishes two things.  (1) My project is locked into a know version of the DLL and won't break unless I change that copy.  (2) When I DO want to change to a newer version of the DLL, I just have to overlay that copy with a newer version and re-compile.    I'm not sure if I have answered your question, but I hope it helps.

Doug

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I updated my question to clarify.  I want to know whether it's possible to stop Visual Studio from putting dlls in the ProjectAssemblies folder.

Comment: Why? `AppData` is where applications are allowed to store their own data, instead of eg writing into the protected `Program Files` folder. Why do you care what gets written in there? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Richard, I'm sorry I didn't understand your question.  I don't have an answer for you.  When I look in the same location on my computer( I have versions 10.0, 11.0, 12.0 and 14.0, that folder is completely empty and I must have over 100 projects that I have created.